# Rank normal form of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

There is a standard result in matrix theory that goes like this: Suppose $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix of rank $r$, then there exist two non-singular matrices $E$ (of size $m\times m$) and $F$ (of size $n\times n$) such that $A=ENF$ where $N=\pmatrix{I_r&0\\ 0&0}$ that is $I_r$ is the identity matrix of order $r$ and the $0$s here are null matrices. But how to prove this?
Please help.

Comment: You have asked over ten questions on this site and it is now time to learn how to format mathematical expressions at this site using TeX and MathJax. For some basic information about formatting, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex). You may also click the "edit" option under your question or other questions/answers to learn the TeX markups of some mathematical expressions.

Comment: Please do not vandalize questions.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Row operations on the matrix $A$ can be expressed by nonsingular square matrices on the left of $A$, and similarly column operations can be expressed as nonsingular square matrices on the right of $A$. If this is unfamiliar to you, you should take a look at [the wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrices) on the subject.

Using row and column operations, you can reduce $A$ to the form of $N$ like this: $XAY=N$. To get $E$ and $F$ in your description above, you just need to invert $X$ and $Y$ to get: $A=X^{-1}NY^{-1}$. Those are your choices for $E$ and $F$.