# Similar/Equivalent matrices and field extensions

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and $F' \supseteq F$ be a field extension.  Suppose $A, B \in M_n(F)$ are equivalent in $M_n(F')$, so there exist $P, Q \in GL_n(F')$ such that $A = PBQ$.  Is it necessarily true that $A$ and $B$ are equivalent in $M_n(F)$?

How about if "equivalent" is replaced with "similar"?

Comment: For "similar", it is true and is a particular case of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9162/conjugacy-rank-of-two-matrices-over-field-extension .

Comment: For "equivalent" (I think the standard word for this is "congruent"), it is true because [each matrix is equivalent to its rank normal form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371497/rank-normal-form-of-a-matrix) (and of course, the rank of a matrix does not change when we extend the field).

Comment: Thanks for the replies!  Very helpful.